# How to detect a change in data inside the tab in custom admin module of Magento

Tags: magento, module, magento-1.7

While editing the elements in the custom admin form, how can i check whether the form has been edited to the last saved data of the form. Is there any way I can check this using any inbuilt magento functions or should I write the validation for every field in the form for changes. I have multiple tabs in my form for further notice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ Class [Varien_Object](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Object/Varien_Object.html)

Methods

- hasDataChanges()
- getOrigData()